# price slide bar in javascript to give appropriate result

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

My table:

```
     <?php
    $s=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  bus_detail where source_point='$_SESSION[source_point]' && destination_point='$_SESSION[destination]'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($s))
{
?>
<ul id="products"> <li data-price="<?php echo $row['price'];?>">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Bus Operator</td>
<td>Bus No.</td> 
<td>Price</td>
     </tr>

 <tr>  
<td><?php echo $row['bus_name'];?></td>  
<td><?php echo $row['bus_no'];?></td> 
<td><?php echo $row['price'];?></td>
</tr>
 <?php }?>
</table>
</li></ul>
```

price slide bar:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
function showProducts(minPrice, maxPrice) {
$("#products li").hide().filter(function() {
    var price = parseInt($(this).data("price"), 10);
    return price >= minPrice && price <= maxPrice;
}).show();
}

$(function() {
var options = {
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 800,
    values: [50, 200],
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        var min = ui.values[0],
            max = ui.values[1];

        $("#amount").val("$" + min + " - $" + max);
        showProducts(min, max);
    }
}, min, max;

$("#slider-range").slider(options);

min = $("#slider-range").slider("values", 0);
max = $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1);

$("#amount").val("$" + min + " - $" + max);

showProducts(min, max);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>
<label for="amount">Price range:</label>
<input type="text" id="amount" style="border: 0; color:#41924B; font-weight: bold;" />
</p>
<div id="slider-range"></div>
```

I've included my price slide bar into my my table page.. it's showing me result but not in a proper manner.. I want to display the result according to the price chosen in the range.. 1st the range is starting from 400 automatically & as per the table is in while loop, it's showing result with different tables. I want to show them in same table according to the range.. Any help ??

Answer (score 0):

put your while code inside your table. it is currently on loop and creating multiple table elements.

also you could use a div instead of table. easier to style/position etc.

Comment: may I ask where you put it?

Answer (score 0):

change that

```
   id='products'
```

to

```
   class = 'products'
```

and change it in the jquery too. Also the while loops generates one ul and one table per iteration. If you do  want that to happen, place the ul and table outside the while loop.